# Unclear Construction of Basis for Tensor Product

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra

My problem lies in page 363 of Steven Roman's Advanced Linear Algebra ([Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3bgrzqznei5qlbr/135%20-%20Roman%20S%20-%20Advanced%20Linear%20Algebra%20%283rd%20Ed,%202008%29.pdf)'s a link).
The author says that for each ordered pair $(e_i,f_j)$ where $\left\{e_i\right\}_{i\in I},\left\{f_j\right\}_{j\in J}$ are respective bases for vector spaces $U,V$, we "invent a new formal symbol" $e_i\otimes f_j$. He then defines $T$ (that will soon be taken as $U\otimes V$) to be the vector space with basis $$\mathcal{D}=\left\{ e_i\otimes f_j \mid i\in I,j\in J\right\}$$
Without further remarks.
Why is $\mathcal{D}$ a basis? We don't know anything at all about $e_i\otimes f_j$ as they're just symbols..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He takes $D$ to be that set $D = \{e_i \otimes f_j\}$, where all elements are just formal symbols.

Then he is defining $U \otimes V$ to be the free vector space $\text{Free}(D)$,
which is the set of all functions $f : D \to \mathbb{F}$ which are zero except at finitely many values of $D$. If you read about free vector spaces, you'll see that $D$ is indeed a basis of $\text{Free}(D)$ (basically by definition).

edit: Here are some references which I recommend on this subject: Dummit and Foote's *Abstract Algebra* and Werner Greub's *Multilinear algebra*.

Comment: you mean which are zero except at finitely many values of $D$ ?

Comment: Thanks. The author makes no mention of free vector spaces as a prerequisite for this chapter. Is it possible to avoid them and still follow the book's construction?

Comment: mercio: whoops, thanks, i'll fix that.

Sai: I don't believe so, but if you're familiar with free groups then it's just like taking the free group on a set. You should also look into the universal property of the tensor product, i.e. bilinear maps $U \times V \to \mathbb{F}$ get turned into linear maps $U \otimes V \to \mathbb{F}$, but it should be noted that the universal property is not a construction. We actually need to do this construction to show that the tensor product exists.

Comment: Gotcha. The universal property for bilinearity preceded the construction in the book and I understand it. At any rate, from what I've just read, free vector spaces seem like nice things. I'll get on to them! Thanks again!